# Python : How to read Key Value pair from CSV file?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a csv file having 3 columns and I want to read 1st and 3rd column as key value pair. I am doing it like below but it's not working.

```
with open(dirName + fileName) as f:
       for line in f:
            (key, value) = line.split(',')
```

Comment: Try `for line in f.readlines()`. But then again there is a native `csv` module or you could use `pandas.read_csv` if you don't mind using a heavy package :). also a friendly suggestion, use `pathlib` as it is easier to compose filenames instead of relying on the `+` thing on strings. You can run into major problems on different platforms

Comment: How will you use the key-value pairs later?

Comment: This is not working out. Do you have another way ?

Comment: Vorsprung durch Technik  @ I created a dictionary function for my program. There are lot of values and so am reading through CSV file as key value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you want something like:

```
with open(dirName + fileName) as f:
       for line in f:
            fields = line.split(',')
            assert len(fields) == 3
            (key, _, value) = fields
```

But maybe glance at the csv module.

Comment: @dstromberg..Your code is working. Just a query. What does it mean (key, _, value) = fields ?

Comment: It's unpacking 3 values from fields into three variables: key, _ and value.  _ is a name that gets  used for "ignore this" a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're working with csv files use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).
As @Buckeye14Guy says: you should also use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for path manipulations.
And, for fast lookup, you can store key-value pairs in a dictionary, `d`.

```
import csv, pathlib

d = {}
your_path = pathlib.PurePath(dirName).joinpath(filename)
with open(your_path,'r') as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for line in reader: 
        d[line[0]] = line[2] # dict entry with key = 1st col and value = 3rd col
```

Comment: Why use a `dict` instead of a `tuple`?

Comment: @chepner: it's a good question. I'm trying to anticipate what the OP would need, and I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open(file,'r+') as text:
 for line in text.readlines():
     (key, value) = line.split(',')
```